# ImageView of a custom CollectionViewCell is nil when it should be configured

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `tableViewCell` with a `collectionView`, `collectionView's cells` are custom ones, they contains just a `imageView`.

[Here is my test project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ovvjhb2rfdayj5u/CollectionViewTest.zip?dl=0)

Here are `DataSource` required methods from my `CollectionView class`:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ImageCell", for: indexPath) as! ImageCell

    let image = UIImage(named: listItems[indexPath.row])
    cell.testImageView.image = image

    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return listItems.count
}
```

When I try to set image for cell's imageView I get this `error`:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

I have checked `image`, it isn't `nil`, but `testImageView` is, I get this error when I try to set image to collectionViewCell's testImageView.
How can I fix it?
**EDIT1**
[image]

Here is method called from `tableViewController` to fill collectionView's `listItem`

```
func load(listItem: [String]) {
    self.listItems = listItem
    reloadData()

}
```

Also if I remove code from `collectionView cellForItemAt indexPath` with this one all is working fine

```
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ImageCell", for: indexPath)
let imageView = UIImageView(image:UIImage(named: listItems[indexPath.row]))

cell.backgroundView = imageView
```

Comment: testImageView, is it added from the interface builder as an IBOutlet?

Comment: Did you connect the outlet of image view ?

Comment: @Ahmad F yes it is
@ Midhun MP yes i did

Comment: so check listItems array, is it instantiated and contains elements?

Comment: It has to be instantiated otherwise no cells would show. It's also dequeuing properly with that force-cast. Only way it could be null is the outlet. Restart XCode and check if the outlet is set. Make sure there's no typos. Make sure the outlet is weak:  `@IBOutlet weak var testImageView: UIImageView?`

Comment: @Ahmad F I have added an image that shows that first element is not nil

Comment: sounds good, but where are you filling listItems array?

Comment: @Brandon tried with no result(((

Comment: @AhmadF this method is called from `tableViewController` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` `tableview dataSource` method i have added this to the question

Comment: If you calling load function in viewDidAppear it won't work, are you?

Comment: @AhmadF but I have no viewDidAppear methods

Comment: so where is it called? if some how it get called after reaching the dataSource methods, it will show you what are you facing right now.

Comment: Can you post you ImageCell class. Posting the whole project in such a scenario as well would really help too, or at least the relevant files.

Comment: BTW, do initialise your cell from xib or from Storyboard?

Comment: @IlyaLapan I've added  link to my project, thank you in advance;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have mistaken your two view controllers. Your IB outlet is connected to a cell in a different view controller. I mean you can have multiple views in different controllers connected to a same IBOutlet, but in your case the one that loads first is not connected, so that is why it crashes.

This is the cell your outlet was connected to. 
[image: This is the cell your outlet was connected to.]

This is that you are trying to load (but did not connect IBOutlet to image view):

[image]

Comment: Oh really, copy-paste method failed me) Sorry for wasted time(

Comment: @astrolka BTW, just a heads up, the way you are mixing Objective-C and swift is kind of weird. Is there a particular reason for such an approach?

Comment: when I try to do the same but on obj-c nothing data source method is not called, [here for more info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40194032/uicollectionview-delegate-method-cellforitematindexpathindexpath-is-not-called) :D

Comment: This definitely sounds like a mistake. You should not mix Objective-C and Swift like that for no good reason. Your code is a mess, to be honest, I recommend you start again. You are not getting MVC right, you view is your data source. The point of MVC is that your data and your view talk through a controller. And for some reason, all of this is embedded in to a table view, which is weird. The reason your data source method was not called is that you probably forgot to set your controller as the data source of the table view

Comment: actually I cannot figure out how to divide my data from controller, that's why I store my data in controller as far as I know it's not a bad practice, is it? I'll be pleased to you if you give me a good example how to use MVC

Comment: I think the reason is in smth else as i mentioned in that post, when i add a height constraint to CollectionView datasource method is called.

Comment: CollectionView: UICollectionView, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate - your data source is a subclass of UICollectionView, but it should be subclass of UICollectionViewController. You should be using viewController instead of a view, there is a big difference. Try again, but this time using a good tutorial and follow it closely. I guarantee if you do it right, everything will work as expected without any weird tricks. If you are not sure what to do or have a problem, open a new question and link it to me, so I can anwser. This is getting out of the scope of the this question.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you want to use code instead..

```
import UIKit


class ImageCell : UICollectionViewCell {

    private var imageView: UIImageView!
    private var descLabel: UILabel!

    public var image: UIImage? {
        get {
            return self.imageView.image
        }

        set {
            self.imageView.image = newValue
        }
    }

    public var imageDesc: String? {
        get {
            return self.descLabel.text
        }

        set {
            self.descLabel.text = newValue
        }
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        self.initControls()
        self.setTheme()
        self.doLayout()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        self.initControls()
        self.setTheme()
        self.doLayout()
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    func initControls() {
        self.imageView = UIImageView()
        self.descLabel = UILabel()
    }

    func setTheme() {
        self.imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

        self.descLabel.numberOfLines = 1
        self.descLabel.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
        self.descLabel.textAlignment = .center
        self.descLabel.textColor = UIColor.black

        self.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    }

    func doLayout() {
        self.contentView.addSubview(self.imageView)
        self.contentView.addSubview(self.descLabel)

        self.imageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.leftAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
        self.imageView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.rightAnchor, constant: -5).isActive = true
        self.imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true

        self.descLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.leftAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
        self.descLabel.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.rightAnchor, constant: -5).isActive = true
        self.descLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.imageView.bottomAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
        self.descLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -5).isActive = true

        for view in self.contentView.subviews {
            view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        }
    }
}


class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    private var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    private var dataSource: Array<String>!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.initDataSource()
        self.initControls()
        self.setTheme()
        self.registerClasses()
        self.doLayout()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func initDataSource() {
        self.dataSource = ["Image1", "Image2", "Image3", "Image4", "Image5", "Image6"]
    }

    func initControls() {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 117, height: 125)
        layout.invalidateLayout()
        self.collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        self.collectionView.delegate = self
        self.collectionView.dataSource = self
    }

    func setTheme() {
        self.collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge(rawValue: 0)
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    }

    func registerClasses() {
        self.collectionView.register(ImageCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "ImageCellIdentifier")
    }

    func doLayout() {
        self.view.addSubview(self.collectionView)

        self.collectionView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        self.collectionView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        self.collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        self.collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

        for view in self.view.subviews {
            view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        }
    }

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.dataSource.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ImageCellIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! ImageCell

        let imageName = self.dataSource[indexPath.row]
        cell.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
        cell.imageDesc = imageName

        return cell
    }
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySD7W.jpg

[image]

Answer (score 0):

maybe the "testImageView" outlet variable is not connected from the interface builder or there is no CollectionViewCell with reuseIdentifier "ImageCell". Check whether cell is nil or not using LLDB po command.

Comment: If there is no reuseIdentifier "ImageCell" then it would throw an error on dequeCell method

Comment: It is connected, reuse identifier is ok and cell is not nil, I really cannot figure out what is wrong here(((

Comment: @astrolka is you cell designed in Storyboard or in a nib/xib file?

Comment: @IlyaLapan in Storyboard, in a few minutes I'll add project

Comment: @astrolka ... try removing ''.png" from the image names while adding them to listItems array.. I have been through this kind of errors many times.. I think this should work.

Comment: can you add the project ?

Comment: @ManojKarki hmmm I've just added dropbox link https://www.dropbox.com/s/ovvjhb2rfdayj5u/CollectionViewTest.zip?dl=0